# How to find the source of static files in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a site in developer mode and all static files are loaded from pub/static but they aren't there. I have seen the docs that describe how Magento looks for the appropriate file to return as it can come from the theme, from extensions or from core files. But how can I know which file is being delivered?

I.e. this URL: https://dev.site.com/static/version1670060873/frontend/theme/sub/es_ES/js/ga_events.js

How can I know where is the real file "ga_events.js"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in developer mode then first remove **pub/static/frontend/theme/sub/es_ES/ga_events.js** file physically and then reload the page so it will generate the soft link of your removed file then execute the below command.

**ls -ls pub/static/frontend/theme/sub/es_ES/ga_events.js**

Then it will show you the symbolic link to the original file using which it got generated.

**For example in my case :-**

[image]

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

Comment: It works perfectly, the symlinks are not visible in FTP but they are there, I just had to look. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` command in bash.

```
find . -name "ga_events.js"
```